# How to change the header message in hugo theme

Tags: hugo

I am new to hugo and using the following play list from youtube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qtIqKaDlqXo&list=PLLAZ4kZ9dFpOnyRlyS-liKL5ReHDcj4G3 to create and deploy static website. It makes use of the following theme: https://github.com/giraffeacademy/ga-hugo-theme

I have used above playlist and deployed my static website on following link: https://naresh-chaurasia.github.io/connect2naresh. Everything is working fine.

The message in the header is coming from file https://github.com/Naresh-Chaurasia/blog-code/blob/master/themes/ga-hugo-theme/layouts/partials/header.html

**Note**: I have checked in my entire hugo code at following link for your reference: https://github.com/Naresh-Chaurasia/blog-code

**Question**: My question is that I want to change message on the header of following page and all other pages: https://naresh-chaurasia.github.io/connect2naresh/soft-skills/eq1/.
How can I change the text that is displayed in header.

Comment: How do you want to change it? The eq1 page is showing the title of the content, which makes sense to me. That uses the "single" page template. If you want to modify the page header for the List pages, you would need to add _index.md page in those directories. Add a title value in the frontmatter. And then modify the list.html template to pass the .Title value to the header.

Comment: Did you fix it?